# BluePrism Excel Extraction

Tags: excel, blueprism

I am trying to extract values from excel which looks like this:

[image: img1]

I want to get the values(x or o) for a specific alphabet (a,b,c… so on) based on the current date, for eg: if today it’s 04/19 I should get value “o” for C and D in the same way “x” for other alphabets.

Thanks,
Anjali

Comment: To get this done efficiently I would recommend writting an Excel macro with VBA. You can always have BP launch the workbook and/or interact with the macro once the workbook is running. Trying to get BP to directly do all this conditional content interaction with Excel is in my experience just too slow and prone to environment issues.

Answer (score 0):

If every calendar date is visible in the excel file, then it would be enough to:

1. Use Format Date function together with a Today function: `FormatDate(Today(), "MM/dd")`
2. Search in the spreadsheet the result from step 1.
3. Return the column index of the cell in step 2.
4. Read the contents of that column.

If there is a reason why dates Monday and Tuesday are merged the same way as Thursday and Friday, it will require a more complex logic.